# more reliable way to check for duplicate files with PHP

Tags: php

I have seen the questions and answers about using md5 and sha1 hashes as well as the file sizes to compare the files, I setup the system and while this works most of the time there is one specific case where it matches false positives with identical md5, sha1 hashes and file size.

Specifically my case it happens when users upload pictures directly from ipad and iphones even though the images are actually totally different.

I am wondering if anyone knows of a different method to add to the check that is more reliable and unique.

Thank you.

edit: also using the file size in bytes

Comment: `there are many cases where it matches false positives with identical md5 and sha1 hashes.`

You're doing something wrong.

Comment: I have a hard time believing that this is the case.  Most likely you are not hashing the files correctly.

Comment: You have to hash the contents of your files not only the file names. You're doing it wrong. When hashing the contents your check should be accurate enough to filter duplicates.

Comment: @BenjaminPaap You think that's what he's doing? His problem would make sense then. Boris, if this is the case, please follow Benjamin's advice!

Comment: I will post some code shortly, I do use the file contents, the only time it matches false positives is in the situation I described when the files get uploaded directly from the camera of ipad or iphone

Comment: @Boris Then maybe the problem lies with way you try to open those files. Maybe you're not opening them properly, failing to do a proper checksum, and failing to perform error checking. All these would result in similar symptoms that you are experiencing.

Comment: md5 collisions are trivial to produce these days, and sha1 is become easier, but I haven't heard of anyone being able to SIMULTANEOUSLY collide both hashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a combination of MD5 and File size, this should be very accurate.

Are you sure that there is no error when creating the hash? It is very unlikely to get a lot of false positives.

Comment: MD5 checksum should be enough if you do it properly. The chances that there will be a collision is minuscule.

Comment: actually forgot to mention I do also use the file size, so all those three metrics are identical.

Comment: @boris well then there most certainly is something wrong with your method.
Usually MD5 alone is good enough.

Comment: there must be something to do with the direct camera upload from ipad because it only happens to those uploads nothing else.

Comment: actually looking at the files the sizes are slightly different but the code does check, so I will have to do some debugging there. thank you for the help